# Spring JPA, @SqlResultSetMapping mapping to JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Application:Spring boot

I am trying to map Non entity class to JPA repository with  `@SqlResultSetMapping` 
and `@NamedNativeQuery`.

I am getting following error while running the application:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cityAddressRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityAddressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.city.strom.core.domain.CityAddressEntity
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]

Any help will be appeciated, Is any thing wrong in my implementation

**CityAddress.java**

```
public class CityAddress { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4860426805452667396L;

    private Integer objectid;
    private String streetname;
    private String streetnumber;


    public Integer getObjectid() {
        return objectid;
    }
    public void setObjectid(Integer objectid) {
        this.objectid = objectid;
    }
    public String getStreetname() {
        return streetname;
    }
    public void setStreetname(String streetname) {
        this.streetname = streetname;
    }
    public String getStreetnumber() {
        return streetnumber;
    }
    public void setStreetnumber(String streetnumber) {
        this.streetnumber = streetnumber;
    }

}
```

**CityAddressEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="cityaddressmap",
    entities={
        @EntityResult(
           entityClass=CityAddress.class,
              fields={
                  @FieldResult(name="objectid", column="ID"),
                  @FieldResult(name="streetnumber", column="STREETNUMBER"),
                  @FieldResult(name="streetname", column="STREETNAME")
              }         
        )
    }
) 
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="CityAddressEntity.AllCityAddresses", 
    query="select OBJECTID, ADD_NUM STREETNUMBER, trim(ADD_STREET || ' ' || ADD_STREET_TYPE) STREETNAME from SWPF_PARCEL_V;", 
    resultSetMapping="cityaddressmap")
public class CityAddressEntity implements Serializable{ 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4860426805452667396L;

    public CityAddressEntity()
    {

    }
}
```

**CityAddressRepository.java**

```
public interface CityAddressRepository extends JpaRepository<CityAddressEntity, Long>{

    @Query(name="CityAddressEntity.AllCityAddresses")
    public List<CityAddress> AllCityAddresses();

}
```

Comment: is some one can help on this please?

Answer (score 5):

CityAddress is not entity, use targetClass instead entityClass. Try something like that:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="cityaddressmap",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
           targetClass=CityAddress.class,
              columns={
                  @FieldResult(name="ID", type=Integer.class),
                  @FieldResult(name="STREETNUMBER", type=String.class),
                  @FieldResult(name="STREETNAME", type=String.class)
              }         
        )
    }
)
```

and add constructor to CityAddress

```
    public class CityAddress { 

        private Integer objectid;
        private String streetname;
        private String streetnumber;

        public CityAddress(Integer objectid, String streetname, String streetnumber) {
           this.objectid = objectid;
           this.streetname = streetname;
           this.streetnumber = streetnumber;
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use `@FieldResult` with `@ConstructorResult`. This answer is wrong.