# Map custom postgres sql type to JPA or JDBC in spring

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a postgres stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search() RETURNS SETOF search_result
```

In this case 'search_result' is a custom (non persistent) type, created like this:

```
CREATE TYPE search_result AS (o offer, distance int)
```

Consider "offer" as another complex type (in this case a table).

Now I'd like to have this somehow on the Java side, either using JPA/Hibernate or JDBC.

In the JPA case, I'm struggling with the mapping search_result, because it's not an @Entity (not a table)... it's just a return type. Also, the embedded "offer" is an issue.

I tried this [1], but it doesn't work for me.

In the JDBC case, I see for each row in the ResultSet two entries: "o" and "distance" which is fine, but for "o" (offer) I have to somehow register a converter. How to do this, especially in a Spring Boot context?

[1] [Spring JPA, @SqlResultSetMapping mapping to JPA repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815728/spring-jpa-sqlresultsetmapping-mapping-to-jpa-repository])

Comment: If you use `select (o).*, distance from search()` you would get the individual columns from the `offer` type in the result set, instead of a single column for the offer as a composite type. That result is probably much easier to handle with the obfuscation layers

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name ... many thanks. The problem with this solution is, that the search result might be extended: `CREATE TYPE search_result AS (o offer, u user, distance int)`. In this case: What if o and u have overlapping field names (created_at, id, ...)?

Comment: Using composite types like that are a great idea if you have full control over the Java code that processes the results (or if everything is handled "inside" Postgres). If you are limited by the features of an obfuscation layer like JPA I would not use such an approach. In that case using scalar data types in the result of the search function will give you a lot less headaches

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .. thanks. I'll decompose it into `search_result`, although the code will be hard to maintain :-/